# Show column information for several columns

Tags: mysql

I can get needed information used the `SHOW COLUMNS` command for all columns or one column (with `LIKE id=''`).
But how I can get the info for several columns, e.g remotely like `SHOW [id, name, email, valid] COLUMNS FROM table`?

Comment: Which information do you exactly need?

Comment: Field and Type.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
SELECT column_name, data_type 
FROM information_schema.columns 
WHERE table_name = 'MyTable' 
AND column_name IN ('Col1','Col2','Col3')
```

will give you the column name and its corresponding data type.

For more information, see the [MySQL reference](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/columns-table.html)